# Maven isn't working in eclipse but in console. Why?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a problem with the integrated maven eclipse plugin (m2e). I am using eclipse oxygen and maven 3.5.2.
Eclipse isn't downloading any dependencies desclared in the pom.xml of a project, nor it is building any projects. But if I build the project via console commands it is working propperly!

First I thought it is a proxy problem but I configured the proxy in eclipse like that:

[image: eclipse network connection dialog]

I also tried to change the "Active Provider" but nothing worked.

The next try was to put the proxy information in the maven settings.xml and even that did not do the trick.

My settings.xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0                       
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<proxies>
 <proxy>
   <id>msgProxy</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <host>i.do.not.tell.you</host>
   <port>1234</port>
   <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
 </proxy>
</proxies>
<profiles/>


</settings>
```

The eclipse maven installations Dialoge, looks like that:

[image: maven installation dialog]

If I try to create a new Maven Project from an archetype, this error messages appears:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
webapp:pom:1.0
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
webapp:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
connect timed out
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
webapp:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
connect timed out
```

[image: error message in eclipse, while fetching maven archetypes]

If I start to update a project, it seems maven needs for ever to download something...

[image: Long download process]

Do you have any advices left for me? If yes, I would be very thankful for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you have in `window->preferences->maven->installations`? And if you are under a coorporate network you may need some user and password for the http(s)

Comment: I am not sure, if we need user credentials for the https part, but for the http part I am sure, we don't. I have added a screenshot of the Maven installations dialog in eclipse, too.

Comment: so just to understand, from the CLI you've tried with the same settings.xml and the same version of mvn, yes? And when you go in eclipse on `your project -> right click -> maven ->update Project` then happens nothing?

Comment: Also check that your Window->Preferences->Maven->User Settings points to your settings.xml in the maven 352 install.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock The path to the user settings is pointing to the correct settings.xml. The one in my .m2 directory.

Comment: @Edwin Yes, that is correct. It is working via CLI but not inside eclipse. If I do update my project via eclipse it seems like he is downloading for ever. I will make a picture of that, too.

Comment: Removed the entries from your pom file related to codehaus cause that does not exist anymore...

Comment: @khmarbaise  
I have added another error message, when I try to create a maven project via an archetype. It seems to me, that maven can't establish a connection. I have also removed the codehouse entries.

Comment: Don't make links to images better put the text in your questions (many people can't access the images)...

Comment: @khmarbaise ok, I put the error message as text and image in the question above.

Comment: Base on the error message `Could 
not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
connect timed out` I would say you are not allowed to access maven central....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
We have an own nexus in our company. So, I added the repository to my settings.xml...
Problem solved and thanks for your help